# How to cross-compile an application with library dependencies for Yocto Linux?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, gstreamer, yocto

I wrote an application on my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) that depends on GStreamer and would like to cross-compile it for my Yocto Linux target (iMX6S-Wandboard). How do I cross-compile the application so that it runs on the target board and is able to use the GStreamer libraries?

Thank you,

Toan

UDPATE:

My Makefile:

```
PACKAGES            = gstreamer-1.0

override CFLAGS     += `pkg-config --cflags $(PACKAGES)` -Wall -Wextra "-DDATADIR=\"$(DATADIR)/\"" -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
override LIBS       += `pkg-config --libs $(PACKAGES)`
override LDFLAGS    += -Wl,--gc-sections

OBJS    = basic-tutorial-7.o
DEPS    = $(foreach file,$(OBJS),$(basename $(file)).d)
EXE     = basic-tutorial-7

DESTDIR     ?=
PREFIX      ?=  $(HOME)/.local/
BINDIR      ?=  $(PREFIX)bin
DATADIR     ?=  $(PREFIX)share/$(PKGNAME)

.PHONY : clean install uninstall

all:    $(EXE)

$(EXE)  :   $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(OBJS) : %.o   :   %.c %.d
    @[ -d "$(@D)" ] || mkdir -p "$(@D)"
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(DEPS) : %.d : $(PROJECT_ROOT)%.c
    @[ -d "$(@D)" ] || mkdir -p "$(@D)"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -M -MF $@ -MT "$(basename $@).o" $<

clean:
    rm -fr $(EXE) $(OBJS) $(DEPS)

install : $(EXE)
    install -DT -m 0755 $(EXE) $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(EXE)

uninstall :
    rm -v $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(EXE)

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), clean)
-include $(DEPS)
endif
```

My *.bb file:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Basic Tutorial 7"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

DEPENDS = "gstreamer1.0 pkgconfig-native gstreamer1.0-plugins-base"

FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}/basic-tutorial-7 ${bindir}/basic-tutorial-7"

EXTRA_OEMAKE += "DESTDIR=${D}/ DATADIR=${datadir}/basic-tutorial-7 BINDIR=${bindir}"

do_compile () {
    oe_runmake install
}

do_install () {
    oe_runmake clean
}
```

Build log:

```
$ devtool build basic-tutorial-7

NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
NOTE: Reconnecting to bitbake server...
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#1)...
Loading cache: 100% |############################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1298 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |##########################################| Time: 0:00:00
Parsing of 773 .bb files complete (772 cached, 1 parsed). 1299 targets, 63 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
Loading cache: 100% |############################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1298 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |##########################################| Time: 0:00:00
Parsing of 773 .bb files complete (772 cached, 1 parsed). 1299 targets, 63 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
Initialising tasks: 100% |#######################################| Time: 0:00:01
Sstate summary: Wanted 0 Found 0 Missed 0 Current 322 (0% match, 100% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
NOTE: Setscene tasks completed
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1480 tasks of which 1480 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
```

Deploy log:

```
$ devtool deploy-target basic-tutorial-7 root@192.168.0.101

NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
NOTE: Reconnecting to bitbake server...
NOTE: Retrying server connection (#1)...
Loading cache: 100% |############################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1298 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |##########################################| Time: 0:00:00
Parsing of 773 .bb files complete (772 cached, 1 parsed). 1299 targets, 63 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
ERROR: No files to deploy - have you built the basic-tutorial-7 recipe? If so, the install step has not installed any files.
```

Comment: What OS are you using on your laptop and on your ARM board? Is gstreamer installed on the board, and how did you install it?

Comment: Hi. My PC is using Ubuntu 14.04. My board is using Yocto distro. GStreamer is installed by default on my board(iMX6 Solo).

Comment: Do you have the Yocto source code installed on your PC, i.e. did you build Yocto on the PC?

Comment: Also, do you have a BitBake recipe for your application?

Comment: No, I don't. I use Yocto distro from Wandboard. My full board name is iMX6S-Wandboard. If I make that distro I can add gcc via editing local.conf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Yocto eSDK](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html) allows you to cross-compile applications for your Yocto target on your PC using exactly the compiler and libraries used for the target itself. There is no need to add GCC to the target. The eSDK can be generated from a Yocto source tree, but since you have the source installed anyways, you don't need to install the eSDK and can build directly from the source. All of this is not ARM specific but the general Yocto workflow to cross-compile for a specific Yocto target.

To do this, first setup the Yocto build environment as usual by changing into the Yocto directory, running `source setup-environment yourbuilddir`.

Then, run [`devtool add`](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#sdk-use-devtool-to-add-an-application), pass the name of your application (will be used for the BitBake recipe) and the path to the existing source tree, e.g.:

```sh
devtool add myhelloworld /home/user/Projects/myhelloworld
```

This will automatically generate a recipe and add a layer named `workspace` to your Yocto source tree. The recipe will be named something like `/yocto/source/path/yourbuilddir/workspace/recipes/myhelloworld/myhelloworld.bb`. You can edit it by running

```sh
devtool edit-recipe myhelloworld
```

Prefix the command with something like `EDITOR=gedit` to use your favourite text editor. Modify the recipe to build your application correctly; BitBake will automatically determine whether to run `make` or `CMake`. An example using `make` would be:

```
DESCRIPTION = "My GStreamer Hello World"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

DEPENDS = "gstreamer1.0 pkgconfig-native"
FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}/myhelloworld ${datadir}/myhelloworld"

EXTRA_OEMAKE += "DESTDIR=${D}/ DATADIR=${datadir}/myhelloworld BINDIR=${bindir}"

do_install() {
    oe_runmake install
}

do_clean() {
    oe_runmake clean
}
```

`DEPENDS` lists the dependencies, I added `gstreamer1.0` and also `pkgconfig-native` which is neccessary when using `pkg-config` inside the `Makefile`. You can add more dependencies to `DEPENDS` if you need them, for example `boost openssl`.
A suitable example makefile would be:

```
PACKAGES            = gstreamer-1.0

override CFLAGS     += `pkg-config --cflags $(PACKAGES)` -Wall -Wextra "-DDATADIR=\"$(DATADIR)/\"" -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
override LIBS       += `pkg-config --libs $(PACKAGES)`
override LDFLAGS    += -Wl,--gc-sections

OBJS    = main.o
DEPS    = $(foreach file,$(OBJS),$(basename $(file)).d)
EXE     = myhelloworld

DESTDIR     ?=
PREFIX      ?=  $(HOME)/.local/
BINDIR      ?=  $(PREFIX)bin
DATADIR     ?=  $(PREFIX)share/$(PKGNAME)

.PHONY : clean install uninstall

all:    $(EXE)

$(EXE)  :   $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(OBJS) : %.o   :   %.c %.d
    @[ -d "$(@D)" ] || mkdir -p "$(@D)"
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(DEPS) : %.d : $(PROJECT_ROOT)%.c
    @[ -d "$(@D)" ] || mkdir -p "$(@D)"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -M -MF $@ -MT "$(basename $@).o" $<

clean:
    rm -fr $(EXE) $(OBJS) $(DEPS)

install : $(EXE)
    install -DT -m 0755 $(EXE) $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(EXE)

uninstall :
    rm -v $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(EXE)

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), clean)
-include $(DEPS)
endif
```

Inside your `Makefile`, make sure that `make install` installs your application binary into `$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/myhelloworld` and data files (e.g. images) into `$(DESTDIR)$(DATADIR)/somefile`. On the target, your binary will then be located in `/usr/bin/myhelloworld` and the data files in `/usr/share/myhelloworld`. In the `Makefile`, pass `"-DDATADIR=\"$(DATADIR)/\""` to the compiler such that you can open your data files by something like `fopen(DATADIR "somepic.png", "rb");`. For the source file `main.c`, you can use the [GStreamer example 1](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-docs/blob/master/examples/tutorials/basic-tutorial-1.c).

Save recipe, `Makefile` and `main.c`, and then run

```sh
devtool build myhelloworld
```

to compile your application. If all goes well, you can then install it to the target via SSH by running e.g.

```sh
devtool deploy-target myhelloworld root@targethostname
```

You can then SSH to the target and run your application by typing `myhelloworld`. To uninstall it:

```sh
devtool undeploy-target myhelloworld root@targethostname
```

If you later decide to ship your application as part of the Yocto image, modify the recipe for your system image and add:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " yourhelloworld"
```

Keep the space after the first quote. When building the image, your application and data will be included. The main advantage of this approach (using a BitBake recipe) is that adding the application to the image becomes easy, and that the application will be linked against exactly the libraries available on the target, so you can use exactly the features present in these versions.

Using the example makefile above, you can also directly compile for your host PC by simply running `make`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This material is out of my knowledge. It's so great. But as I said I don't build my own Yocto distro. I use Yocto distro which Wandboard built. So, should I use Yocto eSDK ?

Comment: I have some trouble. I have been updated my Makefile and *.bb file above. Well, I built successfully but when I trying to deloy, I got this: 

`ERROR: No files to deploy - have you built the basic-tutorial-7 recipe? If so, the install step has not installed any files.`

Comment: But what kind of local.conf did you suggest editing? That would be part of building your own distro! Anyways, if you don't build your own, you need the eSDK belonging to that very distro, i.e. for the wandboard.

Comment: In your makefile, you need to use `-o $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(BINS)`. Also, listing `basic-tutorial-7.c` as part of your `FILES_${PN}` is not necessary as you don't need the source on your target. It also doesn't work if you don't copy it in your makefile.

Comment: If I add both $(DESTDIR) and $(BINDIR) before /$(BINS). I get an error(which I update above) when I build. But when I use $(DESTDIR) only. I built successfully but I got the first error. 
My basic-tutorial-7 directory: `/home/toanrd/Desktop/basic-turtorial-7`
My poky_sdk: `/home/toanrd/poky-sdk`

Comment: I executed `. /home/toanrd/poky_sdk/environment-setup-armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi /home/toanrd/Desktop/basic-tutorial-7/` when source the environment.

Comment: You need to create the output directory first. I updated the answer with a complete example Makefile which compiles into the source directory and then uses `install` to install the files, which automatically creates the output directory. The example works on my board - video output, awesome ;-)

Comment: Well, I have been updated my Makefile as you. Build is successfully but deploy is still error ?

Comment: What's the error message? `deploy-target` of course requires SSH access and you need to provide the correct username and hostname/IP address.

Comment: This error: `ERROR: No files to deploy - have you built the basic-tutorial-7 recipe? If so, the install step has not installed any files.`
And how can I get executable file for arm ?

Comment: And deploy target is only run application on ARM machine, right ?

Comment: The executable will be somewhere in `/home/toanrd/poky_sdk/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/basic-tutorial-7/1.0-r0/image`. Please show your updated makefile, recipe, build log, deploy log, and output of `find /home/toanrd/poky_sdk/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/basic-tutorial-7/1.0-r0/image`.

Comment: I  found nothing in this directory. That's should make deploy error. And I have been updated all informations.

Comment: Your functions `do_compile` and `do_install` are wrong. Please copy them from my example recipe. Also, you list the same files twice in your `FILES_${PN}`...

Comment: Why does it wrong ? My `do_compile()` ,`do_install()` and yours are the same.

Comment: Oh i see the different. I'm so sorry @@

Comment: What the ... !!!!! Wow, amazing, thank you so much ! It's working. What !!! I can imagine that. I can not done this without your help. Thank you so much !

Comment: Haha, glad to help... Actually, it's good to have it written down so I won't forget how to do it either ;-)

Comment: May you solve this issue for me? I tried to solve it, but I have no idea.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026647/how-to-record-video-and-take-picture-at-the-same-time-with-single-camera-in-gstr

Comment: yea, it's okay.