# Preparing I.MX 8 Nano for development using Debian with QT UI / dotnet core for communication

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, wayland, qtwayland

I am trying to get the above development system working, I am starting with a Varicsite NANO compute module. I am trying to get QT 5 setup to develop. I have been unable to find a good Debian guide on how to do that. I would eventually want the QT application to run in kiosk mode without the Weston desktop.

I have Debian built using their instructions of building Debian for the IMX8 board. It runs fine Weston comes up on boot.
I have installed the following packages on the target device.
sudo
apache2
php
jq
curl
qtwayland5
gdb
gdbserver

I have attempted to follow their guide on getting QT to work for YOCTO(not Debian) and have not gotten it to work. QT is installed but their Debian build does not come with a full sdk. Nor do they detail all of the packages that need to be installed.
I have also tried following this guide, but it was written for an RPI and X11 not wayland/Weston so some of the steps seem wrong especially in all of the packages it wants you to install.
https://mechatronicsblog.com/cross-compile-and-deploy-qt-5-12-for-raspberry-pi/

Is there a good guide on how to do this, I was thinking of trying to combine the two guides by using his lines to set up rsync and such but I still do not have a full SDK without the right qmake.

My host system is UBUNTU 16.04

Comment: You could try Yocto Linux. Write a recipe for your app that depends on Qt, and build it using Yoctos bitbake. That way you can easily cross compile for exactly the libraries that are part of the Yocto image.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60845706/4730685) for an example; substitute gstreamer for Qt. Variscite offers pre-configured Yocto targets with Qt included

Comment: I was using their YOCTO build first, but the team decided they would like dot net core support, which I guess was not an option in yocto sumo without mono. So they asked if I could get debian running with dotnet core and QT.

Comment: There seems to be [some dotnet support](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Building_and_running_embedded_Linux_.NET_applications_from_first_principles). I think that Debian is not very well supported by NXP and Variscite. You could also just ask the Variscite support team

Comment: Yeah, that is mono, I do have an open ticket, but I am not sure they know either. They are the ones that told me to use debian for the dotnet. I figured since QT was you know more available that someone would have a guide for how to cross compile it with debian.

Comment: Oh okay :D on a Debian host, you can [add foreign architectures](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) (here: `arm64`) and then install packages for that using `apt-get` as usual, with the `:amd64` suffix at the package name. Unfortunately, the version numbers have to be identical to the native (amd64) ones, so if these aren't compatible to ones available on the target system, it won't work.

Comment: So is there a step by step guide for making this work? something like https://www.ics.com/blog/building-qt-and-qtwayland-raspberry-pi this except for i.mx 8 nano.

Comment: I don't think so. But you wouldn't need to build anything yourself, just install the arm64 Qt packages.

Comment: So I have been working on this for most of the day. I am at the configure stage. I get the following error.

You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL[_ES2],
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL[_ES2] and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL[_ES2] in the mkspec for your platform.


I think it is because I do not have an /opt/vc folder or libraries. What do i need to install to get those to work.